# Проблема с вычислением в java

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Есть вот такое выражение. Я разбил счёт на две части: правая точка и левая точка. При вычисление этих значений у меня никак не получается получить тот же 0. Получаются очень маленькие величины, которых, по-сути, не должно быть. Пробовал округлять через BigDecimal, но без успешно, какой-то да хвост остаётся. Не подскажите, каким путём можно решить данную проблему? Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Покажите ваш код.

Comment: -0.001 и -1.1102230246251565E-16. Первое я округлил значение, второе нет

Comment: @GennadiyDyomin Нам интересен код вычислений, в частности не очевидно что означает "Пробовал округлять через BigDecimal"

Comment: a.y[1]=a.x.get(k+1)[1]+a.lym*(a.x.get(k+1)[1]-a.x.get(k)[1]);

Comment: a.y[0]= new BigDecimal(a.x.get(k+1)[0]+(a.lym*(a.x.get(k+1)[0]-a.x.get(k)[0]))).setScale(3, RoundingMode.UP).doubleValue();

Comment: Вопрос не очень ясен. Что значит "лева точка, правая точка"? Сформулируйте четче, что вы хотите получить и что получается. Поместите в тексте вопроса свой код (только относящийся к делу, естественно). И почитайте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: -1.1102230246251565E-16 это -1.11 / 10^16, то есть почти  0..., double в java надо сравнивать с учетом потери точности

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25160375/comparing-double-values-for-equality-in-java